# Semantic UI Form Validation "depends" option not working

Tags: jquery, validation, semantic-ui

As of [version 2.2](http://semantic-ui.com/introduction/new.html#dependent-form-validation) form validations support a depending field. However when I try to implement it in my project, it seems that the `depends` option is completely ignored:

```
// HTML
<form class="ui form segment">
  <input type="checkbox" name="is_volunteer" id="is_volunteer" />
  <input type="text" name="volunteer_name" id="volunteer_name" />
</form>

// JS
$('form').form({
  inline: true,
  fields: {
    name: {
      identifier: 'volunteer_name',
      depends: 'is_volunteer',
      rules: [{ type: 'empty' }]
    }
  }
})
```

It's basically the same structure as the shown demo. However, with this the `name` text field always gets validated, no matter if the checkbox is checked or not.

Of course, I tried it also with proper semantic markup, but it's the same result.

I also checked if I'm really using version 2.2, and I am... I also get no debug error or anything else.

Answer (score 1):

Try to include `prompt` parameter.

The rules will become:

```
rules: [{
   type: 'empty',
   prompt: 'Your validation message'
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the demo version is working.

As their [docs](http://semantic-ui.com/introduction/new.html#dependent-form-validation) state:

> Form field validation can now specify a `depends` property which will **only** cause validation to occur only when another field, like a checkbox or input, is selected.

So, if the checkbox is **checked**, validation **will** occur on the text box and will show an error if empty (which is the rule implemented).

If the checkbox is **not checked**, validation **will not** occur on the text box which means **no errors** will show, even if the text box is blank.

This functionality is working as described in the demo, so I think your code should be working as well. Please correct me if there is something I may have misunderstood!

Comment: The truth is it not depends on checked status, it depends on the value not empty.